# Authorize app but also sign in user into ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, authentication

I request authorization for my app through OAuth as described here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/core-concepts/security-and-authentication/browser-based-user-logins/

The sign in dialog appears with something like:

*"**App Name** wants to access your ArcGIS Online account information".*

But the sign in just gives access to the app. Confusingly it does not sign in the user which you can check by going in the same window to www.arcgis.com where you get sign in dialogue again.

**Is there a way to actually sign in user into ArcGIS online?** If I compare it with giving access by Google/Facebook etc, they give not only permission to app but also realy sign in the user.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to log out of your ArcGIS Online account(s), or blow away your browser cache, and try again. It sounds like a pre-existing login is being used when you load the app. You can check the cookies in the browser console if you are really curious.

Here's information on adding users to the ArcGIS Online organization: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/invite-users.htm.

Here's a quick DevLab on how to build a custom ArcGIS API for JavaScript app that uses private layers. This app walks you thru creating a new app with a login to display a layer that is not accessible to the public: https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/javascript/access-private-layers/index.html

Comment: Thank you. My issue is something else. I do not want to add/change members and/or permissions to any data. I want user to be signed in into ArcGIS online after successful signing in into ArcGIS online to approve access of my app. Might sound funny but signing in to approve access of my web application does not sign in user into ArcGIS online, it only gives the app access to user account. But user is not signed in.

Comment: @Miro oh gotcha, I misread. There is not currently a way to sign into a registered app and then sign into ArcGIS Online using that same login. The reverse workflow does work where you can log into ArcGIS Online and then that login will work for the app. There are technical reasons for the current approach, but the pattern you suggested is under consideration.